# ayuda con aws rekognition y php

Tags: php, aws, amazon

Hola buenas tardes estoy usando el SDK de aws y php pero me sale un error y no se como resolverlo agradecería mucho su ayuda gracias de antemano.

```
require '../../vendor/autoload.php';
use Aws\Rekognition\RekognitionClient;

$credentials = new Aws\Credentials\Credentials('*******', '******');

$rekognitionClient = RekognitionClient::factory(array(
        'region'    => 'us-east-2',
        'version'   => 'latest',
    'credentials' => $credentials,
    //'debug' => true, 
));

$compareFaceResults= $rekognitionClient->compareFaces([
    'SimilarityThreshold' => 80,
    'SourceImage' => [
        'Bytes' => file_get_contents("test.jpg")
    ],
    'TargetImage' => [
        'Bytes' => file_get_contents("test1.jpg")
    ],
]);

 $FaceMatchesResult = $compareFaceResults['FaceMatches'];
 $SimilarityResult =  $FaceMatchesResult['Similarity']; //Here You will get similarity
 $sourceImageFace = $compareFaceResults['SourceImageFace'];
 $sourceConfidence = $sourceImageFace['Confidence']; //Here You will get confidence of the picture
```

'Error retrieving credentials from the instance profile metadata server. (cURL error 28: Connection timed out after 1000 milliseconds (see http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html))' in C:\xampp\vendor\aws\aws-sdk-php\src\Credentials\InstanceProfileProvider.php:88 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\vendor\guzzlehttp\promises\src\Promise.php(203): Aws\Credentials\InstanceProfileProvider->Aws\Credentials{closure}(Array) #1 C:\xampp\vendor\guzzlehttp\promises\src\Promise.php(156): GuzzleHttp\Promise\Promise::callHandler(2, Array, Array) #2 C:\xampp\vendor\guzzlehttp\promises\src\TaskQueue.php(47): GuzzleHttp\Promise\Promise::GuzzleHttp\Promise{closure}() #3 C:\xampp\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Handler\CurlMultiHandler.php(98): GuzzleHttp\Promise\TaskQueue->run() #4 C:\xampp\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Handler\CurlMultiHandler.php(125): GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlMultiHandler->tick() #5 C:\xampp\vendor\guzzlehttp\promises\src\Promise.php(246): Gu in C:\xampp\vendor\aws\aws-sdk-php\src\Credentials\InstanceProfileProvider.php on line 88

Answer (score 0):

Al parecer es un problema de conexión, Tienes algún proxy?.

Intenta modificando los parametros del Curl que usa tu librería de Guzzle para que no te vote timeout

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,0);
```